# Passed Variable From Form, Unable to be used in other methods

Tags: c#, forms, variables, methods

Right this is something that should be extremely easy, though for some reason I am having problems,

```
public partial class confSelMenu : Form
{
    public confSelMenu(string mainChoice, string secondChoice, int segNum)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int circSeg = segNum;
        label2.Text = mainChoice;
        label3.Text = secondChoice;
        label4.Text = segNum.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int x1 = circSeg;  <---ERROR HERE

        switch (x1)
        {
            case 3:

                break;

            case 4:

                break;

            case 5:

                break;

            case 6:

                break;

            case 7:

                break;
       }

        wheelMenu wheelMen = new wheelMenu(x1, x2, x3);
        wheelMen.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

I get the error in the **button_click1 event** , with the line;

**int x1 = circSeg**

**The error is as follows:**

**Cannot Implicity Convert Type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' into int**

Here is a bit of background Info:

I have passed 3 variables from a previous form into this one succesffully, and displaying them as Labels in the form (First name (**string**), last name (**string**), a number ranging from 3 - 7(**int**)),

As you can see, I use them in my label.Text, and they display fine,

Now I am trying to make a switch case happen on an event (button click) and I want it to do something different depending on which int they chose (**between 3 - 7**)

But for some reason I get this error from VS 2013, Can someone please help?

Many Thanks!

Comment: I would have preferred If I could put the variable "segNum" directly into the switch case, but if I do that then I get the error "the name segNum does not exist in current context", is there no way to make it global?

Comment: where is circSeg defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following.

```
public partial class confSelMenu : Form
{
int circSeg;
public confSelMenu(string mainChoice, string secondChoice, int segNum)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    circSeg = segNum;
    label2.Text = mainChoice;
    label3.Text = secondChoice;
    label4.Text = segNum.ToString();

}
```

Problem was you have defined it inside the constructor instead it should be defined as instance field.

> > Cannot Implicity Convert Type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' into int

Also would like to point at the **compilation error**!

It seems you have lable on the form named `circSeg`. If it is the case you need to chnage either instance field or name of the label.

Comment: Mate,

You're amazing you knew what I was trying to do EXACTLY, spot on :), I completely forgot that I had changed the name of a Label (in Designer view) but it was not hard coded,

That is why I was getting that error,
Thank you so much ^_^

Answer (score 1):

problem with your code

you defined `circSeg` variable in below method and

```
public confSelMenu(string mainChoice, string secondChoice, int segNum)
{    
    int circSeg = segNum;
}
```

access it in other method , that is the issue ..if you want to access same variable than you need to define that variable in class scope not in method scope

so you need to do like this

```
public partial class confSelMenu : Form
{
 private int circSeg;
  //other code
  void method1()
  {
     circSeg= value;
  }
}
```

declare variable at class level scope not at method level scope which is very important

This very basic issue related to scoping of variable , I suggest you should go and read about scope of variable.

Comment: I have some knowledge with scope of variables,
Though that wasnt the real problem i was experiencing here, I was more confused with the error of "Cannot Implicity Convert Type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' into int",

But I ended up finding the solution :)

Many thanks

Comment: @TaoNinja - welcome ...it happends it just my suggestion dont take it seriously...

Comment: Noted, im always open to suggestions :)
Happy coding ^_^